# Why page numbers are not incremented?

Tags: page-numbering

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,}
\usepackage[a3paper,
            ignoreall,
            hmargin={20mm,5mm},%
            vmargin={5mm}%
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\parindent=0mm

\tikzset{
 node distance = 0mm,
NL/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, semithick, fill=gray!10,
        inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
        text width=#1 mm, minimum height=#2 mm,
        node contents={}},
        }

\newcommand\okvir{%
\begin{scope}[NL/.append style={line width=1mm, fill=none,
                                font=\bfseries, align=flush center}]
\node (f1) [NL=395/287];
\node (f2) [NL=40/15,
            above left=of f1.south east,
            node contents={ZFC}];
\node (f3) [NL=40/15,
            above=of f2,
            node contents={stran \thepage\ od \pageref{LastPage}}];
\node (f4) [NL=110/15,
            left=of f2,
            node contents={Leseni stebri terase v Varsanu}];
\node (f5) [NL=110/15,
            above=of f4,
            node contents={Hiša v Varsanu}];
\node (f6) [NL=35/15,
            left=of f4,
            node contents={\today}];
\node (f7) [NL=35/15,
            above=of f6,
            node contents={Merilo 1:25}];
\end{scope}
                    }
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Questions:

- why the first page is without frame?
- why the page numbers is not incremented?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your frame is processed on the first page, so \thepage is 1. But as it is too large it is then moved to page 2. Enlarging the textheight a bit will keep the frame on page one. But it will not solve the \thepage problem: It is not reliable in this place. You should either put your frames in the header or footer, or use \pageref to retrieve the page number:

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,}
\usepackage[a3paper,
            ignoreall,
            hmargin={20mm,5mm},%
            vmargin={5mm}%
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\parindent=0mm


\tikzset{
 node distance = 0mm,
NL/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, semithick, fill=gray!10,
        inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
        text width=#1 mm, minimum height=#2 mm,
        node contents={}},
        }
\newcounter{okvir}
\newcommand\okvir{%
\stepcounter{okvir}\label{okvir-num\number\value{okvir}}%
\begin{scope}[NL/.append style={line width=1mm, fill=none,
                                font=\bfseries, align=flush center}]
\node (f1) [NL=395/287];
\node (f2) [NL=40/15,
            above left=of f1.south east,
            node contents={ZFC}];
\node (f3) [NL=40/15,
            above=of f2,
            node contents={stran \pageref{okvir-num\number\value{okvir}} od \pageref{LastPage}}];
\node (f4) [NL=110/15,
            left=of f2,
            node contents={Leseni stebri terase v Varsanu}];
\node (f5) [NL=110/15,
            above=of f4,
            node contents={Hiša v Varsanu}];
\node (f6) [NL=35/15,
            left=of f4,
            node contents={\today}];
\node (f7) [NL=35/15,
            above=of f6,
            node contents={Merilo 1:25}];
\end{scope}
                    }
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\advance\textheight by 3pt
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\okvir
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```